# Android TestRunner fails due to IllegalState exception

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, junit

I am running android Instrumentation tests to unit test activity and specifically if the WebView has loaded or not code is as follows, but each time i get exception

> Running tests Test running started Test failed to run to completion.
>   Reason: 'Instrumentation run failed due to
>   'java.lang.IllegalStateException''. Check device logcat for details
>   Test running failed: Instrumentation run failed due to
>   'java.lang.IllegalStateException'

There are no Logcat logs , just this message in console , tried on Genymotion as well as device both are on android 5.0.

Code is as follows

```
public class WebViewActivityTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 <WebViewActivity> {

    WebView webView;
    WebViewActivity testActivity;

    public WebViewActivityTest()
    {
        super(WebViewActivity.class);
    }

    @Override
    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        testActivity = getActivity();

    }

    public void testWebView()
    {
        webView = (WebView)testActivity.findViewById(R.id.webView);
        assertNotNull(webView);
    }

    public void testPreconditions() {

        assertNotNull("Webview activity is null",testActivity);
    }
}
```

I have tried searching but got no clue why this exception is occurring , please help.

Comment: A complete stacktrace would be greatly appreciated

Comment: @Johnco i m getting nothing in logical just this exception on console

Comment: what`s the messages of the exception?

FYI,[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14839162/instrumentation-run-failed-due-to-java-lang-illegalaccesserror][1]

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14839162/instrumentation-run-failed-due-to-java-lang-illegalaccesserror

Comment: @TankSui the exception stack trace doesn't appear in logcat , its only message that i get in console , also links are pointing to different situation i have checked all of them

Answer (score 1):

Add a catch statment after the try stetment and give the try statment an exeption. the syntext might be a little off but that should fix your probleme

```
public class WebViewActivityTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 <WebViewActivity> {

WebView webView;
WebViewActivity testActivity;

public WebViewActivityTest()
{
    super(WebViewActivity.class);
}

@Override
protected void setUp() throws(exeption e) {
    super.setUp();
    testActivity = getActivity();
    catch(exeption e)
    System.out.println("Nope!);

}

public void testWebView()
{
    webView = (WebView)testActivity.findViewById(R.id.webView);
    assertNotNull(webView);
}

public void testPreconditions() {

    assertNotNull("Webview activity is null",testActivity);
}
```

}

Comment: Define well the try/catch block statement.

Comment: You need to decide on `throws` or `try` as your exeption checker.

Comment: To solve your probleme you need an exeption handler and to implement it in the code. for more on the exeptions and their handling, I would recommend this https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/index.html

Comment: @eyalp55 consider reading my comments on question please, i said i didn't get any details in exception stack , nothing to do with exception handling

Comment: I meant that you need to add an exeption handler or somthing of sorts to print out the thing that is causing the error message you recived.