# upgrading android gradle plugin from 1.2.3 -> 1.5.0 = unit tests broken

Tags: android, unit-testing, gradle, android-testing

Currently, my android project is using gradle plug-in version 1.2.3.  I am able to successfully run the unit tests (android tests) using the gradle command "./gradlew clean connectedProductionAndroidTest" where "Production" is a flavor.

However, when I updated my gradle plug-in to 1.5.0, I am getting the following error.

```
17:35:16 Tests on Android SDK built for x86 - 4.2 failed: Instrumentation run failed due to 'java.lang.IllegalAccessError'
17:35:16 
17:35:16 com.android.builder.testing.ConnectedDevice > No tests found.[Android SDK built for x86 - 4.2] [31mFAILED [0m
17:35:16 No tests found. This usually means that your test classes are not in the form that your test runner expects (e.g. don't inherit from TestCase or lack @Test annotations).
```

When I updated the gradle plug-in, I didn't make any changes to the directory structure nor any of my tests.

Here is the code I am using to update the gradle plug-in.  This is in my *root* build.gradle file.

```
buildscript {
    repositories { 
        jcenter()
    }


    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
    }
}
```

I am just wondering if anything has changed between the two versions that might be making my tests fail?

Note that I've placed my tests in "$ROOT/app/src/androidTest/java/..." as specified in the documentation.  Also, in gradle 1.2.3, I had to use the command "./gradlew clean connectedProductionAndroidTest" but in plug-in version 1.5.0, it looks like things have changed. I must now do: "./gradlew clean connectedAndroidTestProduction".  Note the swap of "Production" and "AndroidTest".

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

Here is my app's build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.compileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.buildToolsVersion

    lintOptions {
        disable 'OldTargetApi'
        abortOnError false
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myapp"

        minSdkVersion rootProject.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.targetSdkVersion

        versionCode rootProject.getVersionCode()
        versionName rootProject.getVersionName()

        testApplicationId "com.myapp.test"
        testInstrumentationRunner "com.android.test.runner.MultiDexTestRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles 'proguard.cfg'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release

            multiDexEnabled false
        }
        debug {
            debuggable true
            testCoverageEnabled true
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release

            multiDexEnabled true
        }
    }

    productFlavors {
       production {

       }
    }

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `project.properties` file add this line:

```
manifestmerger.enabled=true
```

and rebuild your app.

If it won't work check this solution:

> I have finally found a solution. The problem was with dependencies
>   indeed, it is still unknown why it used to work and then suddenly
>   refused, but here is how the dependencies should look like for your
>   test module:
>
> [image]
>
> So all in all you need to make sure all your libraries and project
>   libraries are listed for your test module and marked as "Provided"
>   except Robotium lib, which is "Compile".

From: [Instrumentation run failed due to 'java.lang.IllegalAccessError'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14839162/instrumentation-run-failed-due-to-java-lang-illegalaccesserror)

And finally, if you still stuck at this problem:

> Older devices have problems running tests when you have the same
>   dependency in your app and test app that instruments the app.
>
> To work around this issue, you will have to figure out which
>   dependencies cause the problem.
>
> In my case it was both Dagger and Espresso depending on `javax.inject`
>   and this is how it can be "fixed":
>
> ```
> androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.0')
> ```
>
> {
>           exclude group: 'javax.inject'
>       }
>
> If you include more or weirder dependencies, you may have a look at
>   [this
>   build.gradle](https://github.com/abdyer/android-test-demo/blob/master/app/build.gradle).
>
> When using espresso-contrib, you may need to do this:
>
> ```
> androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.0')
> {
>     exclude group: 'javax.inject'
>     exclude group: 'com.android.support'
> }
> ```

From: [Tests fail after Espresso 2 upgrade (failed: Instrumentation run failed due to 'java.lang.IllegalAccessError')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28551989/tests-fail-after-espresso-2-upgrade-failed-instrumentation-run-failed-due-to)

Comment: Thanks for the help! :)